# Graph Algorithm load distribution

Tags: algorithm, graph, load-balancing

I come across the following problem of distributing load over a number of machines in a network. The problem is an interview question. The candidate should specify which algorithm and which data structures are the best for this problem.

We have N machines in a network. Each machine can accept up to 5 units of load. The requested algorithm receives as input a list of machines with their current load (ranging form 0-5), the distance matrix between the machines, and the new load M that we want to distribute on the network.

The algorithm returns the list of machines that can service the M units of load and have the minimum collective distance. The collective distance is the sum of the distances between the machines in the resulting list.

For example if the resulting list contains three machines A, B and C these machines can service collectively the M units of load (if M=5, A can service 3, B can service 1, C can service 1) and the sum of distances SUM = AB + BC is the smallest path that can collectively service the M units of load.

Do you have any proposals on how to approach it?

Comment: How do you define collective network distance? And any proposals you have thought of?

Comment: please detail your question

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach I can think of, is defining a value for every machine, something like the summation of inverted distances between this machine and all it's adjacent machines:
v_i = sum(1/dist(i, j)    for j in A_i)
(Sorry I couldn't manage to put math formula here)
You can invert the summation again, and call it machine's crowd value (or something like that), but you don't need to.

Then sort machines based on this value (descending if you have inverted the summation value).
Starting with the machine with minimum value (maximum crowd) and add as much as load as you can. Then go for the next machine and do the same until you assign all of the load you want.

Comment: Note that if two machines are not adjacent, the distance between them is assumed infinity, so it's inverted factor is zero and it won't effect the summation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like every machine is able to process the same amount of load -- namely 5 units.  And the cost measure you state depends only on the set of machines that have nonzero load (i.e. adding more load to a machine that already has nonzero load will not increase the cost).  Therefore the problem can be decomposed:

1. Find the smallest *number* k <= n of machines that can perform all jobs.  For this step we can ignore the individual identities of the machines and how they are connected.
2. Once you know the minimum number k of machines necessary, decide which k of the n machines offers the lowest cost.

(1) is a straightforward [Bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).  Although this problem is NP-hard, excellent heuristics exist and nearly all instances can be quickly solved to optimality in practice.

There may be linear algebra methods for solving (2) more quickly (if anyone knows of one, feel free to edit or suggest in the comments), but without thinking too hard about it you can always just use [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).  This potentially takes time exponential in n, but should be OK if n is low enough, or if you can get a decent heuristic solution that bounds out most of the search space.

(I did try thinking of a DP in which we calculate f(i, j), the lowest cost way of choosing i machines from among machines 1, ..., j, but this runs into the problem that when we try adding the jth machine to f(i - 1, j - 1), the total cost of the edges from the new machine to all existing machines depends on exactly which machines are in the solution for f(i - 1, j - 1), and not just on the *cost of* this solution, thus violating optimal substructure.)